# Show fancybox with class instead of id

Tags: javascript, class, fancybox

I am at the beginning to learn Javascript. And I hope you can help me.

I want to use a fancybox if someone clicked on a link with a class attribute. I have done it also with an id. With id attributes the code works very fine. But if I cange it with class attributes it doesn´t work.... :(

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

This code works very fine. But why don´t work this one with only class attributes? The code have also the same element as the upper one. Only the following lines of codes have been changed.

```
<button class="myBtnNew">Open Modal New</button>

var myBtnNew = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtnNew");

myBtnNew.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

getElementsBy as it says, resturns multiple elements, a list. So myBtnNew is a list of elements and the list does not have an onclick. So just add the [0] as you did with span :

```
var myBtnNew = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtnNew")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of objects, not just one object. Use this:

```
var myBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtnNew");

myBtns[0].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```